# How to validate relationship between values

Tags: joi

I have a case where there are a few different ways user input should be able to pass validation:

```
// greatly simplified
Joi.object({
  v4Type: Joi.string().valid('DHCP', 'Static'),
  v6Type: Joi.string().valid('DHCP', 'Static'),
  v4Addr: Joi.string().ip({version: 'ipv4'}),
  v6Addr: Joi.string().ip({version: 'ipv6'}),
})
```

The user is required to have at least one address family configured, but we don't care which one. The only configuration that passes the above schema that I need to reject is:

```
{ v4Type: Static, v6Type: Static } // both addrs are missing
```

They need to have at least one address. It can be for either family, and it can be static or dynamic - but if it is static, it must be supplied. In pseudocode:

```
function isValid(...) {
  if ([v4Type, v6Type].include('DHCP')) return true;
  if (v4Addr || v6Addr) return true;
  return false;
}
```

I've followed over a dozen threads here and elsewhere, and haven't found one yet that lets me consider the values of multiple keys at once before deciding pass/fail. I also can't find a way impose a pair of "or'd" constraints on other keys based on one key's value. I've looked into the `switch:` option to `when()` and chaining `when()`'s but all have the same issue.

Here are two pseudo-code Joi schemata that would work, but I can't figure out how to express for real:

```
Joi.object({
  a1: Joi.string().valid('ok', 'need more').
      when({ is: 'need more', then: Joi.object({a2: DHCP}).or(b1: Joi.required()),
  a2: Joi.string().valid('ok', 'need more').
      when({ is: 'need more', then: Joi.object({a1: DHCP}).or(b2: Joi.required()),
  b1: Joi.string(),
  b2: Joi.string(),
})
```

or

```
Joi.object({
  a1: Joi.string().valid('ok', 'need more'),
  a2: Joi.string().valid('ok', 'need more'),
  b1: Joi.string(),
  b2: Joi.string(),
}).when({ is: a1 == 'need more' && a2 == 'need more', then: Joi.keys('b1').or('b2')})
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of v4Type or v6Type is mandatory, if v4Type or v6Type is 'DHCP', v4Addr and v6Addr are optional, and if its 'Static', respective will be mandatory.

```js
Joi.object({
    v4Type: Joi.string().allow('DHCP','Static'),
    v6Type: Joi.string().allow('DHCP','Static'),
    v4Addr: Joi.string().regex(/^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$/).when('v4Type', { is: 'Static', then: Joi.string().required(), otherwise: Joi.string().optional() }),
    v6Addr: Joi.string().regex(/^([\da-f]{1,4}:){7}[\da-f]{1,4}$/i).when('v6Type', { is: 'Static', then: Joi.string().required(), otherwise: Joi.string().optional() }),
}).or("v4Type", "v6Type")
```

Comment: thank you so much for offering a solution. I'm not sure if this meets our requirements: When both types are `Static`, only *one* address is required - not both. We do not force users to have an address in both families, only one. It looks like you are accomplishing that by `or`ing the types - are you suggesting to signal no address in one family by omitting its type? We want the default type to be DHCP, so that would force an address where we don't want one.

Also I noticed you switched from my use of `ip()` to `regex` - was there a particular reason for that?